# Strip removing more characters than expected

Tags: python, string

Can anyone explain what's going on here:

```
s = 'REFPROP-MIX:METHANOL&WATER'
s.lstrip('REFPROP-MIX')   # this returns ':METHANOL&WATER' as expected
s.lstrip('REFPROP-MIX:')   # returns 'THANOL&WATER'
```

What happened to that 'ME'? Is a colon a special character for lstrip? This is particularly confusing because this works as expected:

```
s = 'abc-def:ghi'
s.lstrip('abc-def')   # returns ':ghi'
s.lstrip('abd-def:')  # returns 'ghi'
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`str.lstrip` removes all the characters in its argument from the string, starting at the left. Since all the characters in the left prefix "REFPROP-MIX:ME" are in the argument "REFPROP-MIX:", all those characters are removed. Likewise:

```
>>> s = 'abcadef'
>>> s.lstrip('abc')
'def'
>>> s.lstrip('cba')
'def'
>>> s.lstrip('bacabacabacabaca')
'def'
```

`str.lstrip` does *not* remove whole strings (of length greater than 1) from the left. If you want to do that, use a regular expression with an anchor `^` at the beginning:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'REFPROP-MIX:METHANOL&WATER'
>>> re.sub(r'^REFPROP-MIX:', '', s)
'METHANOL&WATER'
```

Comment: You don't really  need re, just  `s[s.find(sub)+len(sub):]]` or more simply `s[len(sub):]`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Note that this will malfunction if you don't know whether the left prefix is actually there or not - you'd want to add a `if s.startswith(sub):` test first.

Comment: Yep, True,  one way or another lstrip is definitely the tool for the job, split would actually  probably be the best approach `s = s.split(sub, 1)[-1]`, no need to check at all as it will just return the string if nothing matches bar the OP specifically wants to check the start of the string

Answer (score 0):

The method mentioned by @PadraicCunningham is a good workaround for the particular problem as stated.

Just split by the separating character and select the last value:

```
s = 'REFPROP-MIX:METHANOL&WATER'
res = s.split(':', 1)[-1]  # 'METHANOL&WATER'
```