# Remove specific characters from a pandas column?

Tags: python, pandas, strip

Hello I have a dataframe where I want to remove a specific set of characters 'fwd' from every row that starts with it. The issue I am facing is that the code I am using to execute this is removing anything that starts with the letter 'f'.

my dataframe looks like this:

```
  summary 
0 Fwd: Please look at the attached documents and take action 
1 NSN for the ones who care
2 News for all team members 
3 Fwd: Please take action on the action needed items 
4 Fix all the mistakes please
```

When i used the code:

```
df['Clean Summary'] =  individual_receivers['summary'].map(lambda x: x.lstrip('Fwd:'))
```

I end up with a dataframe that looks like this:

```
      summary 
0 Please look at the attached documents and take action 
1 NSN for the ones who care
2 News for all team members 
3 Please take action on the action needed items 
4 ix all the mistakes please
```

I don't want the last row to lose the F in 'Fix'.

Comment: _this is removing anything that starts with the letter ‘f’_ That’s to be expected, look at the documentation for `str.lstrip()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Strip removing more characters than expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34297084/strip-removing-more-characters-than-expected)

Comment: yes i understand, is there a better way to specifically remove cases only with 'fwd:'

Comment: Regex is probably your best bet.

Comment: another option is: `individual_receivers['summary'].str.lstrip('Fwd:').where(individual_receivers['summary'].str.startswith('Fwd:'),individual_receivers['summary'])`

Comment: @ansev That could be simplified using slicing, no?

Comment: yes with `loc`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a `regex` remembering `^` indicates startswith:

```
df['Clean Summary'] = df['Summary'].str.replace('^Fwd','')
```

Here's an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'msg':['Fwd: o','oe','Fwd: oj'],'B':[1,2,3]})
df['clean_msg'] = df['msg'].str.replace(r'^Fwd: ','')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
       msg  B clean_msg
0   Fwd: o  1         o
1       oe  2        oe
2  Fwd: oj  3        oj
```

Comment: Have you tested it? Wasn't ```\b``` a beginning of the word instead?

Comment: This works and helped, but I have an additional question, is there a few to feed in a list of phrases to remove rather than the one individual phrase?

Comment: Sure, regex accepts patterns, which you can use. You can try opening another question with the issue so we address this subject. Post the link to the question as a comment so I can see it, thanks!

Comment: thanks for all the help, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60229899/how-to-apply-regex-for-multiple-phrases-on-a-dataframe-column

Answer (score 0):

You are not only loosing `'F'` but also `'w'`, `'d'`, and `':'`. [This is the way `lstrip` works](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/lstrip.html) - it removes all of the combinations of characters in the passed string.

You should actually use `x.replace('Fwd:', '', 1)`

1 - ensures that only the first occurrence of the string is removed.

Comment: and if `Fwd:` is not at the beginning ?