# How to apply regex for multiple phrases on a dataframe column?

Tags: python, regex, dataframe

Hello I have a dataframe where I want to remove a specific set of characters 'fwd', 're', 'RE' from every row that starts with these phrases or contains these phrases. The issue I am facing is that I do not know how to apply regex for each case.

my dataframe looks like this:

```
      summary 
0 Fwd: Please look at the attached documents and take action 
1 NSN for the ones who care
2 News for all team members 
3 Fwd:RE:Re: Please take action on the action needed items 
4 Fix all the mistakes please 
5 Fwd:Re: Take action on the attachments in this email 
6 Fwd:RE: Action is required
```

I want a result dataframe like this:

```
          summary 
0 Please look at the attached documents and take action 
1 NSN for the ones who care
2 News for all team members 
3 Please take action on the action needed items 
4 Fix all the mistakes please 
5 Take action on the attachments in this email 
6 Action is required
```

To get rid of 'Fwd' I used df['msg'].str.replace(r'^Fwd: ','')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they can be anywhere in the string, you could use a repeating pattern:

```
^(?:(?:Fwd|R[eE]):)+\s*
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `(?:Fwd|R[eE]):` match either Fwd, Re or RE
- `)+` Close non capturing group and repeat 1+ times
- `\s*` Match trailing whitespaces

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wLbuDh/1)

In the replacement use an empty string.

You could also make the pattern case insensitive using `re.IGNORECASE` and use `(?:fwd|re)` if you want to match all possible variations.

For example

```
str.replace(r'^(?:(?:Fwd|R[eE]):)+\s*','')
```

Comment: they will only be found at the beginning of the string

Comment: @muchappreciated Then you could replace the `\b` with `^` https://regex101.com/r/3TZgJ3/1 `^(?:(?:Fwd|R[eE]):)+\s*` I have updated the answer.

Comment: I am thinking why would you pass `(?:` in the beginning instead of `:?` after `Fwd`? It will still match it if it's not in the beginning, or am I missing something?

Comment: @CeliusStingher The first `(?:` is for the group that can be repeated. The second `(?:` is for the alternation to match either `Fwd` or `Re` The `^` is te anchor that asserts the start of the string as the pattern can only occur there.

Comment: should this be applied as so df[summary].str.replace(^(?:(?:Fwd|R[eE]):)+\s*) ?

Comment: No, you should apply with the same formula as in my answer, but with either his or my regex pattern, both seem to work for the examples you provide

Comment: I believed the default behavior was to replace repeating patterns specified in the regex. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The key concept in this case I believe is using the `|` operator which works as **Either** or **Or** for the pattern. It's very useful for these cases.

This is how I would solve the problem:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'index':[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
                   'summary':['Fwd: Please look at the attached documents and take action ',
                              'NSN for the ones who care',
                              'News for all team members ',
                              'Fwd:RE:Re: Please take action on the action needed items',
                              'Fix all the mistakes please ',
                              'Fwd:Re: Take action on the attachments in this email',
                              'Fwd:RE: Action is required',
                              'Redemption!']})
df['clean'] = df['summary'].str.replace(r'^Fwd:|R[eE]:\s*','')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   index  ...                                              clean
0      0  ...   Please look at the attached documents and tak...
1      1  ...                          NSN for the ones who care
2      2  ...                         News for all team members 
3      3  ...      Please take action on the action needed items
4      4  ...                       Fix all the mistakes please 
5      5  ...       Take action on the attachments in this email
6      6  ...                                 Action is required
7      7  ...                                        Redemption!
```

Comment: lets say some of my strings start with Redempetion, the Re is being removed. How do i account for this not to happen?

Comment: How about now? Edited the regex

Comment: Thanks, feel free to accept my answer, every upvote counts! :)